# Create a program to calculate the rez value depending on the set condition

Tags: pascal

```
program z4v2; 
var 
  f, e, O, rez : real;

begin 
  write('f: '); readln(f);
  write('e: '); readln(e);
  write('O: '); readln(O);  

  if abs(f) < 5 * abs(O) then 
    write(ln(abs(2 * f - 3 * (e * 2) * O))) 
  else if 5 * abs(O) < abs(f) <= 7.5 * abs(O) then 
    ln(abs(2 * (f * 2) - 3 * O));     
end.
```

> -->Operation '<=' is not applicable to boolean and real types

How to calculate the value of a function? It doesn't work out for me, I've tried several options, I don't understand much about pascal.

Create a program to calculate the rez value depending on the set condition
[image]

Comment: Are you unsure how to [define the function’s result](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pascal_Programming/Routines#Function_result)? The FPC (FreePascal Compiler) gives you [three options](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Function). Unlike in mathematics, you cannot write an expression such as `5 * abs(O) < abs(f) <= 7.5 * abs(O)`. Granted evaluation is done from left-to-right, the sub‑expression `5 * abs(O) < abs(f)` yields a `Boolean` value. However, `someBoolean <= 7.5 * abs(O)` is not permitted in Pascal; you cannot compare a `Boolean` with a `real` value.

Comment: Hi, I'm in college, we almost didn't pass Pascal at school, and now it's hard to remember something. This is literally the third lesson, 6 of us cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Program z4v2;
var f, e, O, rez:real;
 
Begin
 
write('Введите числo f: '); readln(f);
write('Введите числo e: '); readln(e);
write('Введите числo O: '); readln(O);
 
if abs(f) < 5*abs(O) then
    write( ln(abs(2*f-3*(e*2)*O)) )
else if (5*abs(O)<abs(f) )  and ( abs(f) <=7.5*abs(O)) then
    write( ln(abs(2*(f*2)-3*O) ) ) ;
 
End.
```

or

```
Program z4v2;
var f, e, O, rez:real;
var l1,l2,modF:real;
Begin

write('Введите числo f: '); readln(f);
write('Введите числo e: '); readln(e);
write('Введите числo O: '); readln(O);

l1:=5*abs(O);
l2:=7.5*O;
modF:=abs(f);
if modF<l1 then
rez:=2*f-3*e*e*O
else
if (l1<modF) and (modF<=l2) then
rez:=2*f-3*O
else
writeln('Erorr');
rez:=abs(rez);
rez:=ln(rez);
write(rez)
end.
```

Comment: Neither of the suggestions are correct. `e^2` is `Sqr(e)` and `f^2` is `Sqr(f)`.